# Source analysis iw (.handler = (_handler),)

Tags: c, linux, kernel, netlink

I'm reading the source code [iw](https://github.com/Distrotech/iw) and
I'm stucked in this struct.

I dont't understand what these code mean? (.handler = (_handler), etc...)

How can I understand that or any documents to learn that.

```
    static struct cmd                       \
    __cmd ## _ ## _symname ## _ ## _handler ## _ ## _nlcmd ## _ ## _idby ## _ ## _hidden = {\
        .name = (_name),                    \
        .args = (_args),                    \
        .cmd = (_nlcmd),                    \
        .nl_msg_flags = (_flags),               \
        .hidden = (_hidden),                    \
        .idby = (_idby),                    \
        .handler = (_handler),                  \
        .help = (_help),                    \
        .parent = _section,                 \
        .selector = (_sel),                 \
    };                              \
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This is a macro that unfolds in a static structure.

```
#define __COMMAND(_section, _symname, _name, _args, _nlcmd, _flags, _hidden, _idby, _handler, _help, _sel)\
    static struct cmd                       \
    __cmd ## _ ## _symname ## _ ## _handler ## _ ## _nlcmd ## _ ## _idby ## _ ## _hidden\
    __attribute__((used)) __attribute__((section("__cmd"))) = { \
        .name = (_name),                    \
        .args = (_args),                    \
        .cmd = (_nlcmd),                    \
        .nl_msg_flags = (_flags),               \
        .hidden = (_hidden),                    \
        .idby = (_idby),                    \
        .handler = (_handler),                  \
        .help = (_help),                    \
        .parent = _section,                 \
        .selector = (_sel),                 \
    }
```

If you take a look at the definition of `cmd` struct from `iw/iw.h` file, you would see that the `handler` member is a function pointer taking a whole bunch of parameters and returning int.

```
struct cmd {
    const char *name;
    const char *args;
    const char *help;
    const enum nl80211_commands cmd;
    int nl_msg_flags;
    int hidden;
    const enum command_identify_by idby;
    /*
     * The handler should return a negative error code,
     * zero on success, 1 if the arguments were wrong
     * and the usage message should and 2 otherwise.
     */
    int (*handler)(struct nl80211_state *state,
               struct nl_cb *cb,
               struct nl_msg *msg,
               int argc, char **argv,
               enum id_input id);
    const struct cmd *(*selector)(int argc, char **argv);
    const struct cmd *parent;
};
```

The macro initializes the struct assigning the provided function address to this pointer. The `handler` member now can be used as sort of interface for the struct and one may call the provided function via it.

Comment: can you explain function of "handler = (_handler),", I don't understand what it is used for?

Comment: @tânHoàng You may want to take a look at "designated initializers". `.handler = (_handler)` initialized the field `handler` of the struct with the `_handler` argument from the macro invocation.

Comment: @tânHoàng, I have updated my answer for your question from the comment.